# Error on encrypt a message using Elliptic curve

Tags: c#, encryption

when I encrypt a message using Elliptic curve by clicking on button1 several times (more than 10 times), I get the following error

> index was outside the bounds of the array.

Code is given below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using DiffieHellmanMerkle;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.IO;

namespace TestEllipticCurveDiffieHellman
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        byte[] SecretA = null;
        byte[] SecretB = null;
        try
        {
            ECDiffieHellmanMerkle A = new ECDiffieHellmanMerkle(ECDHAlgorithm.ECDH_384);
            ECDiffieHellmanMerkle B = new ECDiffieHellmanMerkle(ECDHAlgorithm.ECDH_384);
            A.KeyDerivationFunction = ECDHKeyDerivationFunction.HASH;
            B.KeyDerivationFunction = ECDHKeyDerivationFunction.HASH;
            A.HashAlgorithm = DerivedKeyHashAlgorithm.SHA256_ALGORITHM;
            B.HashAlgorithm = DerivedKeyHashAlgorithm.SHA256_ALGORITHM;
            SecretA = A.RetrieveSecretKey(B.PublicKey);
            SecretB = B.RetrieveSecretKey(A.PublicKey);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message,"Win32 Error Message");
        }

        //Alice encrypts the message with her secret key
        string SecretMessage = plain.Text;// "The owl of Minerva only flies at dusk.";
        byte[] SecretMessageByteArray = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(SecretMessage);
        string IVString = "initialV";
        byte[] IVByteArray = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(IVString);
        RijndaelManaged rijndael = new RijndaelManaged();
        ICryptoTransform encryptor = rijndael.CreateEncryptor(SecretA, IVByteArray);
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, Encryptor,CryptoStreamMode.Write);
        cryptoStream.Write(SecretMessageByteArray, 0, SecretMessageByteArray.Length);
        cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
        byte[] cipherText = memoryStream.ToArray();
        memoryStream.Close();
        cryptoStream.Close();

        Encrypted.Text = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(cipherText);

        /* string strcipherTextUni = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(cipherText);
        MessageBox.Show("Encrypted Unicode = " + strcipherTextUni.ToString());*/

        //Bob decrypts the message with his secret key
        ICryptoTransform decryptor = rijndael.CreateDecryptor(SecretB, IVByteArray);
        memoryStream = new MemoryStream(cipherText);
        cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read);
        byte[] clearText = new byte[cipherText.Length];
        int clearTextByteSize = cryptoStream.Read(clearText, 0, clearText.Length);
        memoryStream.Close();
        cryptoStream.Close();
        this.Decrypted.Text = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(clearText, 0, clearTextByteSize);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Your question should contain *text* - including what you're trying to do, where the exception occurs, and what the exception is. You should also read the formatting guide so that your code is formatted properly. Additionally, this looks like a good candidate for a short but complete *console* app - there's no need for a GUI here. With a console app, we can just copy and paste the code, and run it directly.

Comment: Exception occurs at "ICryptoTransform encryptor = rijndael.CreateEncryptor(SecretA, IVByteArray);"

Comment: You mean that it will not work under GUI

Comment: What @JonSkeet means is that if we could help you more easily if you post a *complete* (compilable and runnable) program.  That way, we could run it on our computers, see the error that you get, and help figure out what the problem is.

Comment: How can I import the complete files

Comment: @AbdelhadyNaguib You just need to rewrite your app as a console app. You could start a new console app in Visual Studio, or just use Notepad. Paste in the parts of your code that are relevant to your problem, make sure it demonstrates the error, and copy and paste it into your question above (you are allowed to edit your original post).

Comment: I get the error message when I press encryption button several times (more than 10 times)

Comment: Remove the button-pushing. Make an application that you run at the commandline, that only tries the encryption. This will be a VERY short program, one that people here can easily copy and run to find the error.

Comment: Hi Abdelhady Naguib, welcome to stackoverflow. Never mind those downvotes, just follow the directions that Jon gave you next time around. I've +1'ed you to make up for it.

Answer (score 0):

`Encrypted.Text = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(cipherText);` is likely the culprit.

Random bytes are not character encoding. It might be that an unknown encoding is translated into a substitution or no character at all here. This will happen now and then (as encrypted text is indistinguishable from random).

Use base 64 encoding of the ciphertext instead, there are oodles of examples of how to do this on stackoverflow. Luckily for you the base 64 encoding/decoding is build into the .net API (are you receiving that, Oracle?).

Comment: Thank you very much owlstead. Tell me How to use base 64 encoding/decoding in my example?

Comment: Sure thing: "there are oodles of examples of how to do this on stackoverflow." "oodles" means "many".